# How to open mailto: links in gmail / chrome instead of mail app?

Tags: mail.app, email, mojave

I would like to open `mailto:` links directly in chrome google web app instead of built-in mail app. Is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at your "Mail" app. Then Preferences, General, Default mail app.

Set it to Google Chrome.